# Can I read an SoC ROM Table through AXI-AP with CoreSight 400?

Tags: arm, debugging, jtag

I'm newbie and trying to read ROM Table information by JTAG through the AXI-AP using CoreSight SoC-400. As I understand CoreSight is associated with some APs to support JTAG such as AXI-AP, AHB-AP, APB-AP, JTAG-AP etc.

[image]

[image]

When I connect the CoreSight through JTAG, I can successfully read the ROM Table information. But I got a fail when I try to read ROM table information through AXI-AP.

```
Looking for ROM tables on AP1 (AXI-AP)
AXI-AP ROM table base address detected as 0x00000003
Reading ROM table for AP index 1, base address = 0x00000003
Failed to read ROM table: Failed to read 16 bytes from address 0x00000FF0 on CSMEMAP_1
```

Can I read ROM Table information through AXI-AP or only by APB-AP?

If 'yes', I don't know why AXI-AP is failing. I thought that I could read the ROM Table information using AXI-AP but failed to do so.